# JQuery Tablesorter Pager: Get the currently viewed page number

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have looked through the documentation and a few examples but I can't find an answer to this...

How do you get the current page that is being viewed? It's for the purpose of limiting the number of results returned from a database.

Thanks

edit: updated the name because I realized how vague it was

Comment: I had a count that incremented on page change that I stored globally but that doesn't seem like the right way to do it. I was just wondering if there is an official "getCurrentViewedPage" method or something similiar

Comment: Guessing you missed the link on their page. **Companion plugins > Pager plugin**

Comment: I knew that was there... There is really no documentation though. You can go through the scripts but that's it.

Comment: So go through the scripts then. How else can you expect to learn how it works?

Comment: I am and have been going through them... I was just asking if there was a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the original version of tablesorter (v2.0.5), the page is contained in:

```
// table.config.page = zero-based index
// get the value as follows:
var currentPage = $('table')[0].config.page;
```

---

If you are using the pager from my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), then you can get the page from ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/1a5yu8yq/66/)):

```
// table.config.pager.page = zero-based page index
var currentPage = $('table')[0].config.pager.page;
```

or, if you are including the page select in the pager controls, use

```
$('.gotoPage').val() // one-based page index
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. We ended up just using a count to detect what page they were on

```
$('i.fa.fa-chevron-left').on('click', function() { currentPage -= 1 });
$('i.fa.fa-chevron-right').on('click', function() { currentPage += 1 });
```

Comment: This won't work because if the user clicks the left arrow while on the first page, the `currentPage` variable will be decremented, making the value incorrect.